# Как дублировать вывод cout в файл

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Я использую Google test для тестирования кода на c++. Требуется сохранить то, что Google Test выводит в консоль - в файл. Здесь смысл не перенаправить cout в файл, а сохранить то, что было выведено в консоли в файл. Есть идеи, как это сделать в коде?

Comment: Может, сделать это вне процесса? Пайпнуть в `tee`, который выведет и в stdout, и в файл. Unix-way и всё такое.

Comment: а нужно подумать, а зачем сохранять в файл? может хочется потом это анализировать или в редакторе подсветить. Тогда следует воспользоваться возможностью вывести в xml - https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#generating-an-xml-report

Comment: @KoVadim Помимо данных, выводимых GoogleTest, я вывожу в консоль дополнительную информацию. Если буду использовать GoogleTest xml, то мои данные не будут выведены.

Comment: @D-side - это вариант, но хотелось бы провернуть такое в коде, чтоб можно было наблюдать процесс и при желании остановиться и походить по коду

Comment: Так вывод в консоль останется, как и возможность наблюдать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать паттерн **Составной объект** (Composite) для класса `std::ostream`. Google нашёл вот такую [реализацию](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/126997-c-composite-stdostreams/)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class composite_ostream: public ostream
{
public:
    composite_ostream(ostream& stream1,ostream& stream2):
        ostream(0), s1(stream1), s2(stream2)
    { }

    template<class object> 
        composite_ostream& operator<<(object o)
    {
        s1 << o;
        s2 << o;

        return *this;
    }

    inline composite_ostream &
        operator<<(ostream& (*__pf)(ostream&))
    {
        s1 << __pf;
        s2 << __pf;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    ostream& s1;
    ostream& s2;
};

int main()
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open("console.txt");
    composite_ostream co(cout, f);
    co << "Some text..." << endl; 
    f.close();
}
```

Скопировал её сюда, чтобы не потерялась, если исходный сайт вдруг пропадёт.

**UPDATE** Добавил пример использования, предложенный автором вопроса, пользователем @Olejan.

Comment: Код работает не корректно, когда пытаешься вывести в поток разделённые данные за одну транзакцию. Пример: ```co << "Some " << "text" << "..." << endl;``` выведет в консоль и в файл только первый элемент, т.е. "Some". А если разделить вывод так ```co << "Some "; co << "text"; co << "..."; co << endl;```, то тогда выведется именно то, что мы ожидаем, т.е. "Some text...". Есть какие-то соображения по этому поводу?

Comment: @Olejan, самый простой способ — пусть `operator<<` возвращает `composite_ostream` вместо `ostream`. Внёс изменения в ответ. Подробнее написано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/528460/1051621

Comment: а есть возможность допустить ```std::endl``` в этот вывод? В данный момент при попытке передать ```std::endl``` в ```co``` компилятор ругается (ошибка приведения типов), при наличии ```"\n"``` всё хорошо

Comment: @Olejan Описание [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl). Надо добавить ещё один метод `operator<<`, получающий манипулятор (указатель на функцию) в качестве параметра. Пример [здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/ostream-source.html), строка 130.

Comment: То, что надо - благодарю! Позвольте, я скорректирую код в Вашем ответе с учётом ```std::endl```

Comment: @Olejan, конечно. Вы как раз делаете работающий класс и сможете вставить работающий код. Я по памяти отвечаю, мне пришлось бы создавать проект, чтобы всё это проверить.

Answer (score 1):

Давно натыкался на такое - conio.h функция gettext().

```
char *pText;
pText=new char[(dx+2)*6];
gettext(x,y,x+dx+1,y+2,pText);
```

Скажите если не то что нужно.

Comment: благодарю за ответ. Интересная функция, но не всегда консоль в зоне видимости, чтоб с неё снимать текст. Плюс как-то нужно регистрировать перемещение содержимого на экране - момент не ясный. К тому же [здесь](http://cubook.supernew.org/manual-c/functions/506-gettext) написано, что `gettext()` с Windows не совместима.